# "If the Spark Driver fails, it will be replaced by Worker node" Is it a correct statement?

Tags: apache-spark

"If the Spark Driver fails, it will be replaced by Worker node" Is it a correct statement ?
Does this depend on the Cluster manager ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-streaming, if the Spark App(lication) fails, then this is a Single point of failure, the Node where the Driver runs. The Spark App dies.

> It is not a correct statement.

See https://kb.databricks.com/jobs/driver-unavailable.html.

Note the statement: *No matter how big the cluster is, the functionalities of the Spark driver cannot be distributed within a cluster.*